# What is the best way to load a huge SVG on a React-Native app?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am developing an application that basically its a colaborative drawing tool.

I have a HUGE SVG original drawing (4.5 MB) and the users can login pan and draw their own paintings on this original drawing.

Im using react-native-svg and react-native-svg-transformer. I had tried 2 approaches and both failed or are not good enough:

The first one is adding an asset and importing as:

```
import Earth from './FinalEarth.svg';
```

The problem is that it show me this error:

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
This error is located at:
    in SvgComponent (at DrawView.js:265)
```

The other approach is loading it from an URI. Like this:

```
 <Svg
        style={styles.drawSurface}
        width={this.props.width}
        height={this.props.height}
      >
        <G
          transform={{
            translateX: left * resolution,
            translateY: top * resolution,
            scale: zoom
          }}
        >
         <SvgCssUri
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            uri="myurl//EarthCompact.svg?alt=media&token=3435369a-6fb7-4d05-91ca-b6b7c7a2e28e"
          />
```

With this approach I have 2 issues:

I cannot have a loader. So it shows a blank screen and while it downloads the 4 MB from my server only a blank screen is show.

And then, when loaded, the performance its too bad too when zooming or panning.

Anyone has a suggestion on the best approach for this case?

Comment: Simplify the SVG.

Comment: Or break the drawing up into small pieces and load once piece at a time dynamically as you pan.